# How to check for matching random numbers in Java

Tags: java

I am creating a slot machine game, where if all three numbers match a message "jackpot" is conveyed. And now I want to change this message when only two numbers match to "close", I am struggling to find a way to test that two out of the three numbers match, and not have both messages display.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SlotMachine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean playing = true;
        Random rand = new Random();

        int number1 = rand.nextInt(2)+1;
        int number2 = rand.nextInt(2)+1;
        int number3 = rand.nextInt(2)+1;
        int total = number1 + number2 + number3;

        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("| " + "( "+ number1 + " )" + "( " + number2 + " )" + "( " + number3 + " )" + " |");
        System.out.println("-------------------");

        if(number1*3 == total && number2*3 == total && number3*3 == total){
            System.out.println("|    JACKPOT!!!   |");
            System.out.println("-------------------");
            playing = false;
        }

        if(number1 == number2) {
            System.out.println("|     CLOSE..     |");
            System.out.println("-------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously? Just exhaust the `if`s and check if every combination of 2 of 3 numbers match.. there are only `6 C 2 = 15` options...

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to just use combinations of `numberX == numberY` instead of calculating a `total` and performing multiplications for finding equal numbers? The same applies to your "close" search

Comment: since you are already doing 3 checks for the `jackpot`, why not simply `n1 == n2 && n2 == n3 && n1 == n3`?

Answer (score 4):

If all you care about is the number of unique values (overlaps) then I would simply create a `Set<Integer>` and add the three numbers into it. Because a `Set` only permits unique values, any duplicates will effectively vanish, and so the quantity remaining will show how many different numbers your slot machine generated, giving you the answer you seek.

```
Set<Integer> uniqueNumbers = new HashSet<>(4);
uniqueNumbers.add(number1);
uniqueNumbers.add(number2);
uniqueNumbers.add(number3);

int uniqueCount = uniqueNumbers.size();
if (uniqueCount == 1) {
    // Jackpot code goes here.
} else if (uniqueCount == 2) {
    // "Close" code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Thank, makes far more sense now.

Comment: This is the simplest solution allowing to update the game for a large random pick with any limit of number per pick.